# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean available as request attribute

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to make simple CRUD web application using Java, Spring, Hibernate and MySQL. The problem where I'm stuck is that I cannot display form to add new item (pizza) to database.

Here is my controller:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;

@Controller
public class PizzaController {

  @Autowired private PizzaDao pizzaDao;

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
  public String indexPage(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "index";
  }
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="Pizza/pizzalist")
  public String pizzalist(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
  }
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="Pizza/pizzalist/add")
  public String add(@ModelAttribute("mypizza") Pizza pizza) { //, BindingResult result,         SessionStatus status, ModelMap mmap) {
    //mmap.addAttribute("pizza",pizza);
    pizzaDao.add(pizza);
    //status.setComplete();
    return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
  }
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="Pizza/pizzalist/delete")
  public String delete(@RequestParam("id")long id, Model model) {
    pizzaDao.delete(id);
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
  }
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="Pizza/edit")
  public String edit(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
  }
}
```

And view:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Available pizzas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of All Pizzas</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <c:forEach var="p" items="${pizzas}">
            <tr>
                <td>${p.name}</td><td>${p.price}</td><td><a href="pizzalist/delete?id=${p.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <br />
    <h1>Add new pizza</h1>
    <form:form modelAttribute="mypizza" method="POST" action="pizzalist/add">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><form:input path="price" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
    <br />
    <a href="/pizzashop">Go back to home page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I leave only table displaying available pizzas with links "Delete", everything is displayed OK and deleting also works OK.

I guess something is wrong with form and controller @ModelAttribute but I can't find what is exactly wrong, I am adding same attribute in controller as in form - "mypizza" and this should work (at least from what I was able to find on Google).

Can someone enlighten what prevents this application from working and how to solve the issue? If other config files are needed I can provide them.

UPD:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mypizza' available as request attribute
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pizzalist.pizzalist_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(pizzalist_jsp.java:243)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pizzalist.pizzalist_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(pizzalist_jsp.java:194)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.pizzalist.pizzalist_jsp._jspService(pizzalist_jsp.java:103)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: you need to be more specific (e.g. show us an exception or some debugging outputs)

Comment: you have POST `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="Pizza/pizzalist/add")`, But where is GET ?

Comment: @user2264997 I've posted an answer for you.

Comment: @user2264997, do you really think specific root cause exception message will help you? In any case, I added the message to my post

Comment: @Rembo do you mean I need add method=RequestMethod.GET to the "Pizza/pizzalist/add" controller method? What if I need to submit form using POST specifically?

Comment: @user2375500 There is not force-able to have GET method to process a form, if you want to bind form data to a model bean, then the model bean should be available while the form is rendering. you can add model bean in any way like using `@ModelAttribute("mypizza")` or in GET `model.addAttribute("mypizza", new Pizza());` if you not do either, then `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mypizza' available` raise..

Answer (score 8):

On this method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
  public String indexPage(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "index";
  }
```

you should add the following line:

```
model.addAttribute("mypizza", new Pizza());
```

The `form:form` needs an "empty" model that corresponds to the modelAttribute you defined.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck. Still got the same message. I am  generating .war using Maven (if this is relevant). Tried to add your suggested line as first line of method and also before "return". No difference.

Answer (score 6):

if the `modelAttribute` of `<form:form` is not available while the form is rendering. then the exception will raise, in your case `mypizza` is not available, The exception says the same:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mypizza' available as request attribute
```

---

**you can add model bean/form backing object in any way you like:**

using `@ModelAttribute("mypizza")` :

```
@ModelAttribute("mypizza")
public Pizza loadEmptyModelBean(){
   return new Pizza();
}
```

In your case `@ModelAttribute("mypizza")` option is perfect, instead of adding in every method add it in one place.

---

or in `GET` method (where @Shay Elkayam answer says the same):

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
  public String indexPage(Model model) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    model.addAttribute("mypizza", new Pizza());// model bean added to use in form
    return "index";
  }
```

if you not do either, then `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mypizza' available` exception will raise.

Comment: Good answer. The first option is also effective.

Answer (score 5):

To anyone who may encounter the problem:

I needed to add

```
@ModelAttribute("mypizza")
```

to "pizzalist" method which now looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="Pizza/pizzalist")
public String pizzalist(@ModelAttribute("mypizza") Pizza pizza, Model model) {
   List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
   model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
   model.addAttribute("mypizza", new Pizza());
   return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
}
```

Also, needed to add Shay Elkayam suggested line to same method (I added just before "return" in "pizzalist" method) and to method "add" right at the start, which now looks like

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="Pizza/pizzalist/add")
public String add(@ModelAttribute("mypizza") Pizza pizza, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("mypizza", new Pizza());
    pizzaDao.add(pizza);
    List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
    return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
}
```

And now viewing of table and adding new item works OK. 
If anything, my WEB-INF folder structure is:

```
- jsp
   index.jsp
   - pizzalist
       pizzalist.jsp
```

Thanks to everyone who  tried to help and show the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my 2 cents here. While copying from another page, some of my buttons went outside the end of `</form>` tag.
I had the modelattribute and all related things.  One of my `<form:button>` was **outside** the `<form:form>.... </form:form>`  tags.  It was crazy...

Just putting this answer as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

you want to change this function:-value="Pizza/pizzalist"

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="Pizza/pizzalist")
public String pizzalist(@ModelAttribute("mypizza") Pizza pizza, Model model) {
List<Pizza> pizzas = pizzaDao.getAll();
model.addAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);
return "pizzalist/pizzalist";
```

this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined **modelAttribute** with **form** in your **JSP** then before reloading the JSP, spring will check for that modelAttribute and throw this type of exception if it is not available.

In this case, you have to set this modelAttribute in your controller first to prevent such type of exception.

```
model.addAttribute("myModelAttribute", new MyModelAttribute());
```